# Is it possible to get request headers from one request and send them to another in web console?

Tags: javascript

When I open the 'Network' tab in my web console of a post request which has both response and request headers, in the 'Request Headers' part there is some data send. Is it possible to 'copy' this data and re-send them to another url using fetch with post method?

Comment: Yes. Have you right-clicked on the request copied as fetch to see how that's formatted? It won't be an automatic process, but you can code it.

Comment: Does "copy as fetch" not work? `await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850103/is-it-possible-to-get-request-headers-from-one-request-and-send-them-to-another", { ... });`

Comment: `fetch("url", { method: "POST", headers: { /* headers goes here */ } })`...

Comment: ...for example: `headers: { "User-Agent": "...", "Cookie": "...", "Referer": "..."}`

Comment: Ah, I haven't precised it; I want an automated script that gets those requests and automatically send them via fetch to another url